# Android: drawable resource from earlier API level

Tags: android, android-drawable

Is there a way in Android to use a drawable resource from an earlier Android version / API level then the one of the current project? More specifically, is there a way to access it in the project without putting it into the drawable resource folder manually?

In my specific case, I would like to use `android.R.drawable.btn_check_buttonless_on` from Android 2.2 in a project that uses Android 4.0. Because in 4.0 it's not used anymore, I obviously cannot just reference it like

```
myMenuItem.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_check_buttonless_on);
```

Is there another way to include the drawable resources of earlier versions?

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

https://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=0443546CEE776318BF6D21552A9D1864?recipeId=3823

> many (most?) of the resources are, for one reason or another, marked as non-public; presumably these are intended only for use by particular components. The non-public give a diagnostic that the "Resource is not public". You can still use the non-public one,s but you have to extract the image drawables and copy them into your project.

I'll try it as well.

Edit:

it worked for me:

1. go to your android SDK/platforms/android-19/
2. extract android.jar
3. go to android/res/
4. there you have all the drawables you want to use (inside the drawable folders).

You have to copy all the .png file into your project.